# Recursively filter and delete item in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to deep filter until specific object with id found. I've taken these references,

1. [Recursively filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132146/recursively-filter-array-of-objects)
2. [Filter items in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283944/filter-items-in-array-of-objects)
3. [Recursively filter array of objects with different properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876567/recursively-filter-array-of-objects-with-different-properties)
4. [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript/10024926)

I am able to find the parent node, But was unable to delete specific children. What I'm doing wrong here?

Payload,

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Shrek",
    lock: false,
    checked: false,
    selected: false,
    layers: [],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Fiona",
    lock: false,
    checked: false,
    selected: false,
    layers: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Lord Farquad",
        lock: false,
        checked: false,
        selected: false,
        layers: [
          {
            id: 5,
            name: "Prince Charming",
            lock: false,
            checked: false,
            selected: false,
            layers: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Donkey",
    lock: false,
    checked: false,
    selected: false,
    layers: [],
  },
]
```

I'm getting Parent node with this code, but not sure from where to splice.

```
this.layers.filter(function f(o: any) {
  if (o.id == 5) return true;
  if (o.layers) return (o.layers = o.layers.filter(f)).length;
});
```

Expecting Output:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Shrek",
    lock: false,
    checked: false,
    selected: false,
    layers: [],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Fiona",
    lock: false,
    checked: false,
    selected: false,
    layers: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Lord Farquad",
        lock: false,
        checked: false,
        selected: false,
        layers: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Donkey",
    lock: false,
    checked: false,
    selected: false,
    layers: [],
  },
]
```

Comment: So you want to delete objects with a given id. You also speak of filtering... but I don't see that in the expected output? Or do you mean the same thing with filtering as with as deleting?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to put the data and the code together into a [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to make it runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to build this on top of a reusable function.  I abstracted a `deepFilter` from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442868/1243641) so that we can configure the name of the child nodes (most commonly `'children'`, here `'layers'`, but I've seen many others.)  The returned function takes a predicate and returns another function which takes an array, and recursively keeps only those nodes for which the predicate returns true.

Using this, we can write `removeById` by passing `'layers'` to `deepFilter` along with a predicate that checks if a node's `id` fails to match our target.  It looks like this

```js
const deepFilter = (childProp) => (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (({[childProp]: children = [], ...rest}) => 
    pred (rest)
      ? [{... rest, [childProp]: deepFilter (childProp) (pred) (children)}]
      : []
  )

const removeById = (target) => 
  deepFilter ('layers') (({id}) => id !== target)

const payload = [{id: 1, name: "Shrek", lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [/* onions have layers */]}, {id: 2, name: "Fiona", lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [{id: 4, name: "Lord Farquad", lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [{id: 5, name: "Prince Charming", lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: []}]}]}, {id: 3, name: "Donkey", lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [/* parfaits have layers */]}]

console .log (
  removeById (5) (payload)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If we prefer to call in this manner: `removeById (payload, 5)`, then we can simply write

```js
const removeById = (payload, target) => 
  deepFilter ('layers') (({id}) => id !== target) (payload)
```

The big advantage here is that we can write a reusable function in a simple manner, and find uses all over the place for it, making our custom code extremely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

you were close.

- based on your expected output I think you want to return `o.id != 5`
- if a node has layers then you need to assign those layers to the filtered value of themselves `o.layers = o.layers.filter(f)`

```
function f(o) {
  if (o.layers.length) {
    o.layers = o.layers.filter(f)
  }
  return o.id != 5;
}

let filtered = layers.filter(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Shrek', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [] }, { id: 2, name: 'Fiona', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [{ id: 4, name: 'Lord Farquad', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [{ id: 5, name: 'Prince Charming', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [] }] }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Donkey', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [] }];

const remove = objectScan(['**(^layers$)'], {
  rtn: 'bool',
  abort: true,
  useArraySelector: false,
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value, context }) => {
    if (value.id === context) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(remove(data, 5));
// => true

console.log(data);
// => [ { id: 1, name: 'Shrek', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [] }, { id: 2, name: 'Fiona', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [ { id: 4, name: 'Lord Farquad', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [] } ] }, { id: 3, name: 'Donkey', lock: false, checked: false, selected: false, layers: [] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)